# CSS3 Font Embedding

Tags: html, fonts, css, embedded-fonts

I'm trying to simply embed a font that I have uploaded to my server.

Everything is being loaded correctly, but the wrong font is being displayed. I know this is happening because when I remove the @font-face code the rendered HTML font changes.

Here's my code, I've played around with so many different things in the last hour so shout out whatever you think might work. I've also tried .TTF files.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Joan;
    src: url("../fonts/joan.otf") format('font/opentype');
}
body {
    background: url('../images/bg.gif');
    font-family: Joan;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? .otf won't work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Oh hell no, I'm not using IE. Chrome and FF4

Comment: Refer this tutorial on Pixel2Pixel Design http://www.pixel2pixeldesign.com/css3-font-embedding-html/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Wins for me so far in my related adventures.

[Here's a website](http://bigballoon.businesscatalyst.com/) I'm developing with it as we speak: http://bigballoon.businesscatalyst.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may have to put the font name in quotes. Also, for MSIE compatibility, you'll need to convert the font to .eot format. Here's "bulletproof" @font-face as [per paulirish.com](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/). You may need to adjust depending on full/postscript font name:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Joan';
   src: url('../fonts/joan.eot');
   src: local('Joan Regular'), local('Joan'), 
        url('../fonts/joan.otf') format('opentype'); 
}
```